# Programmatically get CPUs 'detailed' usage, like top/htop

Tags: bash, top, proc

`htop` has a great way to show CPU usage.
It shows the activity (usage in %) of each cores, and each core gauge is divided into three parts :

- blue: low priority processes
- green: normal processes
- red: kernel processes

I'm doing an htop-like in Bash (yep !) for my studies and I'd like to read these values from /proc (in preference), or otherwise from anywhere, commands for example.

top is displaying the same informations (as text) when you press <kbd>1</kbd>.
Eventually this can be a solution to read data from `top` if I can programmatically press <kbd>1</kbd> on background-ed top...

So: is there a simple way to get these informations?

If it is too complicated, read the global usage of the cores can be sufficient (I mean, for example `cpu0: 12%`).

---

**EDIT:** Just wrote this little command to get per-CPU usage, but without more details (so it doesn't answers perfectly my question, but if I can't find a solution I will use it):

```
ps axo psr,pcpu | awk 'END {
  for (E in a)
    print E, a[E]
    }
{ a[$1] += $2 }'
```

Btw, do you think it's reliable?

Comment: You could poke around in `/proc/`, or use `ps` to see the raw information that `top` chews on, and parse it as you like.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a good way to do that.
Please see my edit on the original post, I use `ps` to get global CPUs usage. Do you know what I can add in `ps -o` to get kernel-mode processes? (priority with `-o ni`)

Comment: do `man proc` and search for `stat`

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the load average (1 min, 5min, and 15min average number of non-idle processes) from the output of `uptime`.  Note that this includes processes in disk-sleep, not just CPU-users.

Comment: I needed a "detailed" usage of each CPU, not an abstract number like the load average. Endly, i opted for the use of `/proc/stat`, where you can find global (not per-process) & detailed usage of each CPU core. Htop and top are using this file. I originally wanted a simpler solution but it doesn't exists (and it looks logical when you dig deeper). `/proc/stat` is a formidable file, you just need some documentation and a bit of maths, then you can easily make an htop-killer :D

Comment: oh, I just saw "if too complicated, global usage"... missed the "of the cores".  sorry ><